# HTTP with the Kippt API. Why is this not working?

Tags: ruby, http, https

I'm trying to access the Kippt API with a small test I wrote. It goes like this:

```
require 'net/https'

http = Net::HTTP.new "https://kippt.com/api"
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

request = Net::HTTP::Get.new("/users/*******")
request.basic_auth("*******", "*******")

response = http.request(request)
```

When I run this, Ruby says `getaddinfo: No such host is known`. I should note that I don't want to use any external library for the Kippt API, and that I want to retain this RESTful approach to the URL throughout the program.

Why is this not working? How can I make it work?